# SharePoint Foundation search scope

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Is there any way to create a scope for searches in SharePoint Foundation or am I stuck with the out-of-the-box features?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SharePoint Foundation, you will need Search Server Express 2010 to be able to take advantage of the more advanced search features like scopes.  Search Server Express will essentially deploy a simplified version of the service application available with the full blown SharePoint Server.

Here is the url to [Search Server Express](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee263912.aspx) with requirements and download info.

Answer (score 1):

Foundation search is restricted to the site collection or list / library that the user is in.

These boundaries are removed when moving up to SharePoint Server.